# Could the rotating superfluid halo around a galaxy form a regular Abrikosov vortex lattice and serve as a naturally generated Quantum Matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, bose-einstein-condensate, vortex

Spherical halo (shown in blue) surrounding galaxies could be a superfluid [Bose-Einstein condensate] according to Prof. Justin Khoury's hypothesis and may help to understand dark matter and galactic dynamics [Lasha Berezhiani and Justin Khoury. "Dark matter superfluidity and galactic dynamics"; Physics Letters B, Volume 753, 10 February 2016, Pages 639-643].
[image]
https://penntoday.upenn.edu/news/physicist-theorizes-dark-matter-superfluid

**Big Vortex Lattice:**
The quantum mechanical nature of a Bose-Einstein condensate (BEC) can lead to very unusual phenomena. A particularly striking consequence is that a BEC cannot rotate like a classical liquid. Instead, when a BEC is set into rapid rotation, vortices enter the condensate and arrange themselves into a regular lattice (Abrikosov lattice).
[image]
https://jila.colorado.edu/bec/CornellGroup/gallery/images/vortexnuc_color.jpg

Question:
Besides explaining dark matter, could the rotating superfluid halo around a galaxy form a regular Abrikosov vortex lattice and serve as a naturally generated Quantum Matrix?

Comment: What observable consequences would this have?

Comment: Okay Anders, this not an answer to my question…but I like the british sense of humour.
Maybe the secret is Quantum entanglement (if a holographic Abrikosov lattice develops). What we are learning these days is that in some sense quantum theory is really the dominant force. In the BBC science documentary Einstein’s quantum riddle the hypothesis of a quantum mechanically generated universe is described by Prof. Robertus Henricus Dijkgraaf, Prof. Sean Michael Carroll and Prof. Anton Zeilinger (starting from 54 min 10 sec). https://youtu.be/EtBBDWIfa7o?t=3253

Comment: do you have a link for "rotating superfluid halo around a galaxy ",  not the dark matter hypothesis, but the halo in the figure. why do you call it a superfluid as it is composed of light interacting matter?

Comment: Dear anna v, my question above is based on Prof. Justin Khoury's superfluid dark matter hypothesis and cannot be separated from it as you have suggested. Maybe, FIG. 8. A vortex lattice surrounding a rotating galaxy helps to clarify and here the Link to the corresponding publication: Kerson Huang, Chi Xiong and Xiaofei Zhao. Scalar-field theory of dark matter, International Journal of Modern Physics A; Vol. 29, No. 13, 1450074 (2014) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.1595.pdf

Comment: @UN73  I had found the paper. It is a very reasonable model for dark matter. BUT dark matter by definition does not interact with charged particles. and a model built to describe it cannot have interactions giving rise to light.  It is by construction separable  from the charged particles giving rise to the blue light. see https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2016/03/aa27812-15.pdf

Comment: The link to show that optical halos are modeld with scattering off particles.

Comment: Dear anna v, It is common knowledge that dark matter by definition does not interact with charged particles and the picture “spherical halo around a galaxy” is an artistic vision anyway, so don’t bother too much about it. Please comment on the main topic of my question, whether a regular Abrikosov vortex lattice from a Bose-Einstein condensate can naturally be generated and serve as Quantum Matrix.

Comment: Could the vortices of Abrikosov lattice(s) be entangled and interact (not to say communicate) via AC Josephson effect by exchange of quasiparticles? Similar to what is described here: Autti, S., Heikkinen, P.J., Mäkinen, J.T. et al. AC Josephson effect between two superfluid time crystals. Nat. Mater. 20, 171–174 (2021). https://www.nature.com/articles/s41563-020-0780-y